# Is there a way to print upto an even result in a for loop?

Tags: php, loops, syntax, for-loop

So I have a for loop that outputs something like "1,2,3, 4, 5,6...". Is there way to stop the loop lets say say at the last even number before the loop ends. So lets say if its "1,2, 3, 4, 5" , the loop stops when its at 4?

Comment: This does not sound like your real question.

Comment: Where is the code you are using?

Comment: This seems like a part of the solution for a larger problem. It will help if you define the original problem that you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

```
$n = 5;

$m = $n - ($n % 2); // get the largest even number smaller than $n

for ($i = 1; $i <= $m; $i++)
  echo $i . ' ';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$limit = 5;

$limit -= $limit % 2;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $limit; $i++)
{
  // loop body
}
```